# Infinite loop angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, jsp

I have jsp page in which I call one angularjs function with parameter. The function makes get http request and stores result to variable in controller. But when I call that function from jsp page I get a situation where those http requests are being sent infinitely over and over. How to stop that loop and make only one call to function?

in jsp I have:

```
 {{ getFriends('john') }} //call to angularjs function to retrieve all of John's friends
```

in js:

```
$scope.friends = null;

        $scope.getFriends = function(username){

            $http.get("services/rest/getFriends?username="+username).then(function(response){
                $scope.friends = response.data;
                console.info(response.data);
            }, function(response){

            });

        }
```

I get this errors:

```
angular.min.js:sourcemap:123 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
at angular.min.js:sourcemap:6
at m.$digest (angular.min.js:sourcemap:147)
at m.$apply (angular.min.js:sourcemap:149)
at l (angular.min.js:sourcemap:102)
at XMLHttpRequest.v.onload (angular.min.js:sourcemap:107)
```

Full code of jsp:

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html ng-app = "profil">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/profil.js"></script>

<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="appController">

<!-- {{ getFriends('pera') }} -->
{{ getFriends('${userDetails.username }') }}

Ime: ${userDetails.ime } </br>
Prezime: ${userDetails.prezime } </br>
Korisnicko ime: ${userDetails.username } </br>
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/slike/${userDetails.slika}" alt="${userDetails.username }" height="50px"> </img>

</body>
</html>
```

And controller:

```
@RequestMapping("user-details/{username}")
public String showUserDetails(@PathVariable String username, Model model) throws SQLException {
    model.addAttribute("userDetails",dbHelper.getKorisnik(username));
    return "/profil.jsp";
}
```

Other controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path="getPrijatelji",method = {RequestMethod.GET} , produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
    public List<Korisnik> getPrijatelji(@RequestParam(name = "username") String username) throws SQLException{
        return dbHelper.getPrijatelji(username);
    }
```

Comment: Try returning something inside the .then of your API call

Comment: @Vivz Nothing, still loops.

Comment: Is something rendering on your jsp pages? Are u getting any error in console?

Comment: @Vivz I've just started with jsp so I'm not fully familiar with it, what do you mean by rendering?

Comment: Are you changing your `username` anywhere in your service? On every digest cycle the function `getFriends('john')` will get fired. In that function you are mutating "something" which kick off a new digest cycle. If this repeats more then 10 times, you will get an error.

Comment: @AayushiJain I am not changing anything. I am just displaying details of user in jsp as response to http request .../user/username.

Comment: Can you post your html and service code?

Comment: @AayushiJain edited, hope that is what you asked for.

Comment: @wdc you are calling `getFriends('${userDetails.username }')` in angular expression, you should call it on `ng-init` or any other click event.

Comment: try with ng-click="getFriends('${userDetails.username }')".

Comment: @the_mishra Thanks alot guys, ng-init worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call your function in ng-init instead calling in placeholder or ng-bind.